# npm VS yarn in react native

Tags: react-native

I see yarn is more successful than npm. In some cases when I use npm it throws some problems.
But when I use Yarn on the same thing it will resolve the issue much easier.

Could you please tell me the major difference between the two, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both NPM and Yarn are both package managers. Package Managers is essentially a way to automate the process of installing, upgrading, configuring or removing software.

**Yarn was created by Facebook as an alternative to NPM** ,and **NPM is held by Microsoft.**

from the point of technology both of them do the same, but for frameworks such as React,ReactNative which is maintaining by Facebook , of course they will do something to encourage users to start using their own package manager which is Yarn, of-course Yarn is the best fit for FaceBook-Maintaned framework.

I hope it helps